# How to identify Voids and Comp transaction?

Tags: square-connect

I am using **GET /v1/{location_id}/payments** to list all payments.

I am not able to identify Voids/Comps transaction from the list. Also how to get total number of Items Comped/Voided along with amount and reason using API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comped and Voided transactions are not currently identifiable via API.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any plan to add support for it future?